# The difference between "BLOCKED" and "TIMED_WAITING" on java

Tags: java, multithreading

Our tomcat didn't reponse any request. When I used "jstack pid" to print stack info, I got the following information. I find it was blocked on "Thread.sleep(long)". I think it should be the "TIMED_WAITING". Why?

```
Thread 24836: (state = BLOCKED)
- java.lang.Thread.sleep(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
- com.lagou.base.proxy.MasterTemplateContainer.checkMaster(org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate) @bci=128, line=221 (Compiled frame)
- com.lagou.base.proxy.MasterTemplateContainer.access$1(com.lagou.base.proxy.MasterTemplateContainer, org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate) @bci=2, line=185 (Interpreted frame)
- com.lagou.base.proxy.MasterTemplateContainer$2.run() @bci=8, line=134 (Interpreted frame)
- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=95, line=1145 (Interpreted frame)
- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
- java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=744 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 24835: (state = BLOCKED)
- java.lang.Thread.sleep(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
- com.lagou.base.proxy.MasterTemplateContainer.checkMaster(org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate) @bci=128, line=177 (Compiled frame)
- com.lagou.base.proxy.MasterTemplateContainer.access$0(com.lagou.base.proxy.MasterTemplateContainer, org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate) @bci=2, line=141 (Interpreted frame)
- com.lagou.base.proxy.MasterTemplateContainer$1.run() @bci=8, line=125 (Interpreted frame)
- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=95, line=1145 (Interpreted frame)
- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
- java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=744 (Interpreted frame)
```

My code:

```
private void checkMaster(HibernateTemplate hdao) {
    int loopErrors = errorTimes;
    int loopSuccess = successTimes;
    while(true) {
        boolean success = true;
        try {
            if(hdao == null){
                success = false;
                continue;
            }
            success = checkMasterStatusOnce(hdao);//try access database to get the status
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            logger.error("",e1);
            success = false;
        }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(checkInterval);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

the method is invoked in

```
public void check() {
    for (final JdbcTemplate jdao : jdbcTemplates) {
        threadPoolExecutor.execute(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                checkMaster(jdao);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Feel like using the formatting tools available on this site to indent your code, mark up the code etc?

Comment: You can think what you like, but the Java designers didn't agree with you. No doubt they didn't have the benefit of your views when they designed this about 20 years ago. What's your actual question?

Comment: @EJP: actually he’s right with that point, the thread state of `Thread.sleep` [should be `TIMED_WAITING`. That’s what the specification says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#TIMED_WAITING).

Answer (score 4):

You’re right, the thread state for a `Thread` inside the method `Thread.sleep` should be `TIMED_WAITING`.

To cite the [authoritative source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#TIMED_WAITING):

> `public static final Thread.State TIMED_WAITING`
>
> Thread state for a waiting thread with a specified waiting time. A thread is in the timed waiting state due to calling one of the following methods with a specified positive waiting time:
>
> - `Thread.sleep`
> - `Object.wait` with timeout
> - `Thread.join` with timeout
> - `LockSupport.parkNanos`
> - `LockSupport.parkUntil`

I tested several Java versions (Oracle’s implementation) in the range `1.6` to `1.8`, inclusive, and all show the correct behavior of reporting threads inside `Thread.sleep` with the state `TIMED_WAITING`.

It’s also important to consider [the following statement about `Thread.sleep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)):

> … The thread does not lose ownership of any monitors.

So, since the thread does not lose ownership of monitors, it won’t reacquire monitors. So it shouldn’t be in [`Thread.State.BLOCKED`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#BLOCKED).

So either you are using a different JVM/JRE implementation or a modified `Thread` class, maybe it has been modified via Instrumentation at runtime. In either case, the information you have given in your question are not enough to narrow your problem further.

It would be useful as well to know which version of `jstack` you have used as the output has a different format than I got. Maybe it’s the tool which prints the state wrong…

Comment: java -version

java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

I didn't find any “Lock”.

Comment: I tested with exactly that version with the same results. But, as said, you didn’t use the standard `jstack` tool from that jdk. The output look different. Say what you used to get that output. Or try to use the standard `jstack` command for comparison.